# Cookie Message Responsive

Tags: javascript, css

The issue that I am encountering is making the the cookie message responsive when the browser is resizes. I am able to target specific sizes if the browser if the browser is in that size. However, I am not able to get it to resize as the browser is resizing.

I have attempted the following below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/*Cookie Consent Message Modal Set UP
========================================*/
var cookie_modal = (function(){
    var 
    method = {},
    $overlay,
    $modal,
    $content,
    windowWidth = window.screen.width < window.outerWidth ?
                  window.screen.width : window.outerWidth;
                  
    //Determine if user is using IE
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var isIE = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua);
    
    //Determine which operating system
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
    var isIPadPro = /Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent) && 'ontouchend' in document;  
    
    //Determine if user is on mobile/tablet device
    window.mobileAndTabletCheck = function() {
      let check = false;
      (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
      return check;
      
      alert(check);
    };
    
    // Top the modal in the viewport
    method.top = function () {
        var top = 0;
    };

    // Open the modal
    method.open = function (settings) {
        $content.empty().append(settings.content);
        
        if(mobileAndTabletCheck && typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined'){
            //Following if's checks window size and adjust accordinaly
            if(windowWidth > 280 && windowWidth < 321 ){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 300px)'
                });
            }   
            
            if(windowWidth > 359 && windowWidth < 580){
                if(window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches && !isAndroid){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 505px)'
                    });
                }
                if(window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches && !isAndroid){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 120px)'
                    });
                }
            }           
            
            if(windowWidth > 580 && windowWidth < 779){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 840px)'
                });
            }
            
            if(windowWidth >= 780 && window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches && isAndroid){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 600px)'
                });
            }
            
            if(windowWidth >= 780 && window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches && isAndroid){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 600px)'
                });
            }
            
            if(windowWidth <= 780 && window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches && !isAndroid){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 225px)'
                });
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 780 && windowWidth <= 1024 && window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches && !isAndroid){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 600px)'
                });
            }
            
            if(windowWidth >= 1024 && window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches && !isAndroid){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 1200px)'
                });
            }
            
            if(windowWidth >= 1366 && window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches && !isAndroid){
                $modal.css({
                    width: settings.width || 'auto',
                    height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 900px)'
                });
            }
        }
        
        else{   
            //Following if's checks window size and adjust accordinaly
            if(windowWidth > 380 && windowWidth < 479){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 340px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 430px)'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 480 && windowWidth < 580){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 326px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 410px)'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 581 && windowWidth < 680){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 410px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 400px)'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 681 && windowWidth < 780){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 400px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 390px)'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 781){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 490px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 470px)'
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 811){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 432px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 470px)'
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 992){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 435px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 470px)'
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 1024){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 435px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 470px)'
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(windowWidth > 1276){
                if(!isIE){
                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto',
                        height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 490px)'
                    });
                }
                else{
                    if(isIE){
                        $modal.css({
                            width: settings.width || 'auto',
                            height: settings.height || 'calc(100vh - 470px)'
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        method.top();
        $(window).bind('resize.modal', method.top);
        $modal.fadeIn('slow').show();
        
        //Checks if on Cookie Policy Page
        if(!isIE){
            if(!document.URL.includes('http://testsite.com/cookie-policy/')){
                $overlay.fadeIn('slow').show();
            } else {
                $overlay.hide();    
            }
        } else{
            if(!document.URL.indexOf('http://testsite.com/cookie-policy/')){
                $overlay.fadeIn('slow').show();
            } else {
                $overlay.hide();    
            }
        }
    };

    // Generate the HTML and add it to the Modal document
    $overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    $modal = $('<div class="modal cookie" id="cookieConsent"></div>')
    $content = $('<div class="modal-dialog">');

    //Hide the popup
    $modal.hide();
    $overlay.hide();
    $modal.append($content);

    //Add the Overlay and Modal
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append($overlay, $modal); 
    });
    
    // Close the modal
    method.close = function () {
        $modal.delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
        $overlay.delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
        $content.delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
        $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
    };

    return method;
}());
```

Comment: CSS media queries is better suited for this, rather than trying to do it all via javascript.

Comment: I agree with @Sean, I would highly recommend changing this to CSS media queries. They are cleaner IMO for something like this and also they will work when the user resizes/orients the browser.

Comment: @Sean :  where can I find the most common media queries sizes for all devices?

Comment: @RobertoFlores, Bootstrap is one of the most popular responsive frameworks, and here is its breakpoints: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: @imvain2, Thank You. I was able to make my own. I will take a look at bootstrap

Comment: You shouldn't need to target each device specifically. You can just change the layout/display as needed whenever the screen gets too small for it.